# Sum of elements of my formgroup with ngmodel returns NAN

Tags: angular, typescript

I am in the following scenario:

I have an input called "Stock." This input can be changed as long as the product has no variation.

If the product has variation, I must add the inventory quantity of the variations and put the result in this input called Inventory, and apply a disabled.

The problem is that the products can have N variations, so I must add up all the stocks of these "N" variations and put in my input field.

Currently I did the following, which works palliably, but with some problems that I can not put into production:

My template:

**Input of my inventary:**

```
<input [class.disabled]="controls[0] > 0" [(ngModel)]="produto.estoque" type="text" mask="0000000000"
name="estoque" id="estoque" class="form-control">
   <label [class.disabled]="controls[0] > 0" [class.active]="produto.estoque != null || produto.estoque > 0"
   id="labelestoque" for="estoque">Estoque</label>
```

This function adds a variation to my product:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
   <button (click)="addVariacao()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-plus-square create-icon"
      aria-hidden="true"></i>Adicionar variação</button>
</div>
<form *ngIf="mostraVariacoes" [formGroup]="variacaoForm">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of variacoes.controls; let i = index;">
   <div class="container-fluid animated fadeIn" [formGroup]="item">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
         <div class="md-form form-lg input-modal">
            <input mask="000000000000" [(ngModel)]="controls[i]" (keyup)="soma($event)" #inputestoque type="text"
            name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" class="form-control" id="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">
            <label [class.active]="inputestoque.value != ''" for="estoque_variacao{{i}}">Estoque</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>
</form>
</div>
```

**My typescript:**

```
public controls = {};
produto: Produtos = new Produtos;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.produto.estoque = null;

    //Ao iniciar a tela deve carregar o formgroup padrão das variações
    this.variacaoForm = this.fb.group({

      variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])

    });

  }
```

My function that creates the form group:

// Create a new form group. If it receives the product parameter it fills with the received values ​​(in case of update this function is called to copulate the data). If you did not receive the parameter, increment the formgroup with default values

```
createFormGroup(produto?: any, indice?: number): FormGroup {
    if(produto){
      return this.fb.group({
        valor: produto.variacao[indice].valor,
        preco: produto.variacao[indice].preco,
        sku: produto.variacao[indice].sku,
        tipo: produto.variacao[indice].tipo,
        estoque_variacao: produto.variacao[indice].estoque_variacao, 
        foto_prin_1: produto.variacao[indice].foto_prin_1,
        foto_prin_2: produto.variacao[indice].foto_prin_2,
        foto_prin_3: produto.variacao[indice].foto_prin_3,
        foto_prin_4: produto.variacao[indice].foto_prin_4,
        foto_prin_5: produto.variacao[indice].foto_prin_5,
        foto_prin_6: produto.variacao[indice].foto_prin_6,
        id: '',
        id_produto: '',
        created_at: ''
      });
    }else{
    return this.fb.group({
      tipoProduto: '',
      valor: '',
      preco: null,
      sku: '',
      tipo: '',
      id: '',
      id_produto: '',
      estoque_variacao: 0,
      linkfotovariacao: '',
      created_at: '',
      foto_prin_1: '',
      foto_prin_2: '',
      foto_prin_3: '',
      foto_prin_4: '',
      foto_prin_5: '',
      foto_prin_6: ''
    });
  }
}
```

This is my function responsible for adding the stocks and returning to this.produtos.estoque, it is triggered when keyup happens in some stock input of my variation:

```
soma(){
      let sum = 0;
      Object.keys(this.controls).map(key => {
        sum +=  +this.controls[key];
      });
      this.produto.estoque = sum;
    }
```

1- If I do not add any variation and put a number directly into the Inventory field of my ngModel, the value is entered normally.

2- If I add a variation and add a stock value in this range, my ngmodel is added and everything works perfectly.

The problem happens when I enter more than one variation at a time without filling in the value of the first one before.

My sum is only realized if I fill in all the values ​​of the inputs of my variations. If I leave a variation without filling stock, my ngModel this.producto.estoque stands as NAN.

Sorry for my english

Comment: can you please explain more the reason of the problem ?  "The problem happens when I enter more than one variation at a time without filling in the value of the first one before."

Comment: in case of non filled variation value , what is the expected result ?

Comment: I expect that the elements without values will be 0 to prevent nan

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for you is to check if the value of the `controls[key]` is a number before add it to the `sum` :

```
soma(){
   let sum = 0;
   Object.keys(this.controls).map(key => {
     sum +=  isNan(this.controls[key]) ? 0 : this.controls[key];
   });
   this.produto.estoque = sum;
 }
```

Regards,